# CSS not displaying for google chrome or IE for my php function

Tags: php, css, function

I have a php calendar function which is styled in css, it displays fine in firefox but google chrome and internet explorer simply display a black and white basic table with days of the week and month. Do i need to add vender prefixes somewhere? Edit:for some reason it works once I refresh the page, but when i first run the site on a local host it only displays in black and white. Here is the code:

CSS:

```
/* calendar */
table.calendar      { border-left:1px solid #999; }
tr.calendar-row {  }
td.calendar-day { min-height:80px; font-size:11px; position:relative; }    * htmldiv.calendar-day { height:80px; }
td.calendar-day:hover   { background:#eceff5; }
td.calendar-day-np  { background:#eee; min-height:80px; } * html div.calendar-day-np { height:80px; }
td.calendar-day-head { background:#ccc; font-weight:bold; text-align:center;   width:120px; padding:5px; border-bottom:1px solid #999; border-top:1px solid #999; border- right:1px solid #999; }
div.day-number{ background:#999; padding:5px; color:#fff; font-weight:bold; float:right; margin:-5px -5px 0 0; width:20px; text-align:center; }
/* shared */
td.calendar-day, td.calendar-day-np { width:120px; padding:5px; border-bottom:1px solid #999; border-right:1px solid #999; }
```

php:

```
<html lang="en">
     <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css">
</head>
<body>

    <?php

function draw_calendar($month,$year){

/* draw table */
$calendar = '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="calendar">';

/* table headings */
$headings = array('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday');
$calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row"><td class="calendar-day-head">'.implode('</td><td class="calendar-day-head">',$headings).'</td></tr>';

/* days and weeks vars now ... */
$running_day = date('w',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
$days_in_month = date('t',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
$days_in_this_week = 1;
$day_counter = 0;
$dates_array = array();

/* row for week one */
$calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">';

/* print "blank" days until the first of the current week */
for($x = 0; $x < $running_day; $x++):
    $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day-np"> </td>';
    $days_in_this_week++;
endfor;

/* keep going with days.... */
for($list_day = 1; $list_day <= $days_in_month; $list_day++):
    $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day">';
        /* add in the day number */
        $calendar.= '<div class="day-number">'.$list_day.'</div>';

        /** QUERY THE DATABASE FOR AN ENTRY FOR THIS DAY !!  IF MATCHES FOUND, PRINT THEM !! **/
        $calendar.= str_repeat('<p> </p>',2);

    $calendar.= '</td>';
    if($running_day == 6):
        $calendar.= '</tr>';
        if(($day_counter+1) != $days_in_month):
            $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">';
        endif;
        $running_day = -1;
        $days_in_this_week = 0;
    endif;
    $days_in_this_week++; $running_day++; $day_counter++;
endfor;

/* finish the rest of the days in the week */
if($days_in_this_week < 8):
    for($x = 1; $x <= (8 - $days_in_this_week); $x++):
        $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day-np"> </td>';
    endfor;
endif;

/* final row */
$calendar.= '</tr>';

/* end the table */
$calendar.= '</table>';

/* all done, return result */
return $calendar;
}

/* sample usages */
echo '<h2>March 2014</h2>';
echo draw_calendar(3,2014);

?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: d o you have a live url we can look at

Comment: Could you post the generated html output of the calendar instead of your php code?

Comment: unfortunetly the website isnt live yet, but I just realized that the calendar displays fine once i refresh the page on a local host..it just loads in plain black and white when I first run it for some reason.

Comment: cached css file from pervious version perhaps

Comment: If it works after refresh, maybe it's just a browser cache issue.

Comment: seems to be it, thanks guys